# Change Caption of MessageBox with some variable inside message in Delphi

Tags: delphi, messagebox

How to change the title of message dialog box with some variable inside message. I've tried

```
Application.MessageBox('x * y = ' + result, 'this is title', MBICONINFORMATION);
```

but it shows an error said Incompatible types: 'String' and 'PAnsiChar', I know this is because the 'result' variable is not allow. Any solve? Thanks before

Comment: As this is stringrelated, please mention the delphi version you are using. Moreover, the problem is probably that the function/method "result" is if of type ansistring, changing the whole expression to ansistring. Try replacing result with string(result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reccomend you to use Format function as follows:

`Application.MessageBox(PChar(Format('x * y = %s', [result])), 'this is title', MB_ICONINFORMATION);`

Comment: That will give the same compiler error as the code in the question.

Comment: It looks correct now, but I'm still not sure this adds anything to answer the question. The suggestion to use `Format` may be useful in some cases but it's not what this question is about, so it probably should've been a comment rather than an answer. Either way, downvote reverted, since your answer does include the actual answer to the question now.

Comment: I agree with you, this is more a suggestion than an answer

Answer (score 4):

OK, I've known just put

```
Application.MessageBox(PChar('x * y = ' + result), 'this is title', MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Maybe could be a reference for other.

Comment: Remove the ** from around PChar

Comment: @crefird I assumed the `**` was an attempt to make `PChar` bold (`**text**` normally shows up as **text** here), and have taken the liberty of editing accordingly.